# Is it safe to manually delete django_sessions data rows in ProsgreSQL table?

Tags: django, postgresql

First, let me state that I know about the Django Python session cleanup scripts, but I currently don't have easy access to the shell where the Django framework is hosted.  However, I have access to the backend PostgreSQL database.   I'm trying to reduce the size of the over-data tables, and I noticed that the django_session table now has over 2.8 million rows.  I don't think there's ever been a cron job setup for cleanup sessions since this website started running in 2016.

From what I read, the django_session table stores user sessions when they log in, and if they don't log out, it stores them.  Therefore, could I remove any rows older than a specified date?

```
DELETE FROM public.django_session
WHERE expire_date < '2023-01-01'
```

I plan to test this out on a test server, but I would like to know whether it's the right approach.  Otherwise, I'll have to figure out how to get access to run the shell script to do the cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

From here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/sessions/

> Django does not provide automatic purging of expired sessions. Therefore, it’s your job to purge expired sessions on a regular basis. Django provides a clean-up management command for this purpose: clearsessions. It’s recommended to call this command on a regular basis, for example as a daily cron job.

> Note that the cache backend isn’t vulnerable to this problem, because caches automatically delete stale data. Neither is the cookie backend, because the session data is stored by the users’ browsers.